# Unknown token error for elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created a document in my ES index. I need to run a search query.

This is my search payload.

```
{
"highlight": {
    "require_field_match": true,
    "pre_tags": [
        "<span class=\"searchKeyHighlight\">"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
        "</span>"
    ],
    "fields": {}
},
"query": {
    "query_string": {
        "multi_match": {
            "default_operator": "AND",
            "query": "xyz"
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the error I get.

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
        {
            "type": "parsing_exception",
            "reason": "[query_string] unknown token [START_OBJECT] after [multi_match]",
            "line": 1,
            "col": 170
        }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[query_string] unknown token [START_OBJECT] after [multi_match]",
    "line": 1,
    "col": 170
},
"status": 400
}
```

The col 170 is the colon after multi_match in the search query `"multi_match":{"default_operator"`.

I am using elasticsearch version 5.0.0.

`Version: 5.0.0, Build: 253032b/2016-10-26T04:37:51.531Z, JVM: 1.8.0_102`

I don't understand what is wrong in the multi_match query.

Comment: You can either have a [`multi_match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) query or a [`query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) query, but you cannot mix and match both.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. If you add it as an answer, I will mark this as solved. @vinod_vh gave the same answer, if you don't mind, I can accept that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below query. You can use either [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) or [multi_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html), both you can't use.

```
{
"highlight": {
    "require_field_match": true,
    "pre_tags": [
        "<span class=\"searchKeyHighlight\">"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
        "</span>"
    ],
    "fields": {}
},
"query": {
    "query_string": {
            "default_operator": "AND",
            "query": "xyz"
         }
     }
}
```